# How to share singleton service with two different lazy loaded module in angular 6 without providing it in AppModule providers?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have two different lazy loaded modules like module A and Module B. I have a common view of both the module. so I have created a shared module with a shared component and shared service. as shown below.

shared module.

```
@NgModule({ imports: [ CommonModule, 
], declarations: [ComponentA], exports: [ComponentA], providers: [ComponentAService]

}) export class SharedModule { static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders { return { ngModule: SharedModule, providers: [ComponentAService] }; } }
```

Component A

```
export class ComponentA { constructor(private componentAService: ComponentAService ) }

*) Module A

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: ComponentA canActivate: [AuthGuard], ];

@NgModule({ imports: [ CommonModule, SharedModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes), 
], exports: [], declarations: [], providers: [] })
```

Module B

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: ComponentA canActivate: [AuthGuard], ];

@NgModule({ imports: [ CommonModule, SharedModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes), 
], exports: [], declarations: [], providers: [] })
```

Here I observed that it creates two different instances of service for both the module i.e ModuleA & Module B
I want a single service object for both the modules and without registering my service in APPModule.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to register your service in any module.

What you have to do is

in your service add these lines before class definition

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

// your sevice class
export class ComponentAService {}
```

thats it, don't register your service in any module or any components

Comment: thanks for your reply and I would further like to know that by registering my service using providedIn: 'root' when angular is going register my service in the forRoot list. will it add when my module is lazy-loaded?

Comment: @JayanPatel, Yes angular will add it in the root level only, so all your modules can use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to register a service for a module, if your service is going to be shared in more than one module then provide it in either shared or app module.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class commonService() {
}
```